# Como capturar a mensagem do alert usando o web browser controler?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Estou desenvolvendo um robot usando o web browser controler do Asp.Net C#.

Nesse robot eu preciso identificar algumas mensagem que aparecem no Alert do Javascript.

O site que o Robot está manipulando não é meu, então não tem como eu fazer nenhuma alteração na estrutura do mesmo.

Então, será que tem alguma forma de obter o conteúdo do Alert?

Comment: Testou minha resposta?

Comment: @DiegoMoreno Inicialmente havia entendido que você estava perguntando apenas sobre "o que usar", por isso apenas citei o Selenium WebDriver e não dei nenhum exemplo detalhado. Agora atualizei minha resposta com detalhes mais abrangentes demonstrando como instanciar o WebDriver, como navegar para a página que deverá ser acessada pelo robô e como interagir com elementos, além de como obter o texto da mensagem de alert.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez a melhor alternativa para você seja utilizar o [Selenium Web Driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

Com ele você pode manipular o browser e ter acesso a todos os elementos do DOM, permitindo a você simular um usuário navegando pelo site, e você pode também executar comandos JavaSCript, acessar o CSS, etc.

Segue abaixo um exemplo básico de como obter o texto de um alert usando o Selenium Webdriver:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace ExemploSeleniumWebDriver
{
    // A classe robo deve ser uma classe de teste para ser executado automaticamente.
    [TestFixture]
    public class Robo
    {
        // As ações do robô são implementadas como testes unitários.
        [Test]
        public void LeiaMensagemDeAlert()
        {
            // Usei aqui o driver do Firefox, mas poderia ser de qualquer outro browser.
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            // Navega para a página que criei para simular uma mensagem de alert.
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("TesteSeleniumWebDriver.html");

            // Clica no botão.
            driver.FindElementByName("botaoDeAlerta").Click();

            // Obtém o texto do Alert.
            string textoDoAlert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;

            // Fecha a janela do alert.
            driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();

            // Digita a mensagem do alert no campo de texto da tela.
            driver.FindElementById("campoDeTexto").SendKeys("O alert continha o seguinte texto: " + textoDoAlert);
        }
    }
}
```

Conteúdo do arquivo **TesteSeleniumWebDriver.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo do Selenium Web Driver</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="botaoDeAlerta" type="button" value="Mostrar Alert" onclick="alert('Teste de obtenção da mensagem de alerta via C#.')" />

    <br />

    <label>Selenium WebDriver irá preencher essa caixa de texto com o texto do alerta:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="campoDeTexto" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir a mensagem você que terá que realizar os seguintes procedimentos:

1- Inserir uma tag script na head do seu webbrowser contendo uma nova implementação da função `window.alert`, essa implementação deverá adicionar a string do alert em algum elemento do html.

2- Realizar o procedimento para que o alert seja exibido e consequentemente popular o elemento com a string do alert.

3- Recuperar a string colocada nesse elemento

**Primeiro Passo**

Criar tag script que será inserida

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement tagScript = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement bloqAlert = (IHTMLScriptElement)tagScript.DomElement;
```

Agora definiremos a string representando o conteúdo da tag script:

Você deve implementar o código alert aqui, sabendo-se que receberá a mensagem do alert como argumento

```
bloqAlert.text = "window.alert = function (msgAlert) {
//SE A PÁGINA UTILIZAR JQUERY UM EXEMPLO SERIA
$('#elementoUsadoParaReceberAMensagem').val(msgAlert);
}";
```

**Segundo Passo**

Adiciona a tag script criada ao head do documento carregado no seu webbrowser

```
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
```

Feito isso se o alert for invokado na página a sua mensagem irá para esse elemento html

**Terceiro Passo**

Recupera a string colocada no elemento

```
string mensagemAlert = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementoUsadoParaReceberAMensagem").GetAttribute("value");
```